# Como converter datas em varchar para date no SQL `Firebird`?

Tags: sql, firebird, data, varchar

Há como converter datas em **varchar** para **date**?
Estou tendo dificuldades em realizar buscas entre datas, devido a esta discrepância no banco de dados onde realizo a consulta.

Quando insiro minha linha de código:

```
select *
from TAB_FATURAMENTO
where cd_cliente like '%'
and dt_item between '15/05/2017' and '31/05/2017';
```

O resultado da minha busca me retorna valores de datas anteriores ao meu range.
A coluna `dt_item` está em varchar(10) e armazena os valor no formato `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Quando tento utilizar o `CAST`, tenho o seguinte erro:
    ISC ERROR CODE:335544334

```
ISC ERROR MESSAGE:
conversion error from string "22/07/2008"

STATEMENT:
TIBOInternalDataset: "<TApplication>.frmMain.dlgWisql.<TIBOQuery>.<TIBOInternalDataset>."


Statement: select *
from TAB_FATURAMENTO
where cd_cliente like '%'
and CAST(TAB_FATURAMENTO.dt_item as DATE) between '15/05/2017' and '31/05/2017';
```

Comment: Isto também deve ser convertido `between '15/05/2017' and '31/05/2017';`, ou coloque as datas neste formato between `20170515' and '20170531`;

Comment: select * from TAB_FATURAMENTO where cd_cliente like '%' and cast(TAB_FATURAMENTO.dt_item as date) between cast('15/05/2017' as date) and cast('31/05/2017' as date); // Seria isso, @Maurivan? Ou há outra forma de fazê-lo?

Comment: Sim, você pode testar com os tipos date ou datetime. Ou pode converter desta forma também: `CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR (10), '13/05/2017', 103))`.

Comment: @Maurivan: O gerenciador de banco de dados é o FIREBIRD. Acho que não há função convert() no Firebird.

Comment: Isso mesmo @JoséDiz, no Firebird não há esta função. Até agora ainda não consegui resolver este problema..

Answer (score 0):

Coloque assim
`select *
from TAB_FATURAMENTO
where cd_cliente like '%'
and dt_item between **"15/05/2017"** and **"31/05/2017"**`

com Aspas Duplas que vai eu faço assim.

Comment: Eu tive dificuldades e achei isso em um forum `between "15/05/2017" and "31/05/2017"`